# Global variable in javascript does not seem to reflect changes made in different functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I should start by noting I am extremely inexperienced with Javascript.

I have a program in javascript that declares a variable right at the start, in global scope, as follows

```
var psycho_pairs
```

Later I write to this variable with the following

```
async function experimentInit() {
  psycho_pairs = [];
  let num_samples = 10;
  let num_repeats = 4;
  let increment = (high_bound - low_bound)/(num_samples);
  for (let i = low_bound + increment/2; i < high_bound; i += increment){
      let f2_low  = Math.max(i - 1,low_bound);
      let f2_high = Math.min(i + 1,high_bound);
      let f2_incr = (f2_high - f2_low)/(num_samples);
      for (let j = f2_low; j < f2_high - f2_incr/2; j += f2_incr){
          for (let n = 0; n < num_repeats; n++){
              psycho_pairs.push([i,j]);
          }
      }
  }
  console.log(psycho_pairs);
}
```

That final line prints what I expect it to, so thats good.  Later on in the program I have the following lines of code

```
function routine_2afc_stimRoutineBegin(snapshot) {
  return async function () {
    console.log(psycho_pairs);
    let rand_ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * psycho_pairs.length)
    var cur_pair = psycho_pairs[rand_ind];
    var psycho_pairs = psycho_pairs.splice(rand_ind,1);
    console.log(cur_pair);
  }
}
```

In this case the first `console.log` just prints `undefined` and the program throws the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

It seems to me that the variable `psycho_pairs` is being updated locally within the first function, but that isn't being reflected in the global workspace, so in the second function the variable is still just undefined.  However, I thought the `var` keyword explicitly creates global variables that are mutable inside of functions?  What mistake have I made with the initialisation/creation of this variable?

Comment: Why is anything “async” here? That aside, you create a *new* “psycho_pairs” variable in your nested function and because of “variable hoisting” its initial value is undefined.

Comment: The function declarations are not up to me - they are given by the framework I am working in.  So if I remove the `var psycho_pairs` in the nested function that should solve the problem?  I shall try now

Comment: Oh yep, that fixed it, thank you!  If you post an answer I can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript `var` variables have a strange property where they are initialized at the top of the block, and then set wherever you set them. In your second function, you are re-declaring `psycho_pairs`, bringing a local variable called `psycho_pairs` into scope, even though the declaration is below your console.log.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: So in case it isn't obvious, the fix in this case is to remove the `var` keyword from the start of that assignment.